# How to ignore comma in text para when saving in .csv format?

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, gsub, rentrez

I am trying to extract data from NCBI using different functions in `rentrez` package. However, I have an issue because the function `extract_from_esummary()` in rentrez results in matrix, where text of a column is splitted into adjacent columns when saved in .csv file ( as shown in Image) because of "," is recognized as a delimiter.

```
  library (rentrez)
  PM.ID <- c("25979833", "25667274","23792568","22435913")

p.data <- entrez_summary(db = "pubmed", id = PM.ID  )
pubrecord.table <- extract_from_esummary(esummaries = p.data ,
                                         elements = c("uid","title","fulljournalname",
                                                      "pubtype"))
```

[image]

From the image example above, In Column PMID: 25979833, the journal name split to extend into the next column. `European journal of cancer (Oxford`in columns 1 and then `England : 1990)` in next column. When I did a dput(pubrecord.table), I understood that the split is because the words are separated by comma ",". How can I make R understand that`European journal of cancer (Oxford, England : 1990)` belongs to the same column ? Similar issue with the Title and Pubtype fields.... where the long text has a comma in between and R breaks it by csv format. How can I clean the data to so that data is in appropriate column ?

Comment: Without knowing how you `server.R` works is hard to give an opinion.. a `if(is.na(input$PMID)) return(NULL)` before the `sapply` might work.

Answer (score 1):

I thought this looked like a bug in `extract_from_esummary`. I searched package's issues on Github for "comma" and got [this](https://github.com/ropensci/rentrez/issues/65), which says:

> This is not really a problem with rentrez, just a property of NCBI records and R objects.
>
> In this case, the pubtype field is variably-sized.
>
> When you try and write the matrix it represents the vectors like you'd type them in (`c(..., ...)`) which adds a comma which breaks the csv format.
>
> In this case, you can collapse the vectors and unlist each matrix row to allow them to be written out

The issue page has code examples as well.

Comment: Hi gregor, I raised that issue on github page you referred to. The reason I posted the same Q on SO is to find if there is a generalized solution for this issue. If you notice, the Github example address the pubtype field . However, depending on your PMID the variable fields vary... Title or Journal name or pubtype or something else. So, thought this simple change in code will fix everything  `pubrecord.table[,] <- sapply(pubrecord.table[,], paste, collapse=" & ")`. But, I get an error 
```Error in apply(pubrecord.reference, 1, unlist) :  dim(X) must have a positive length```

Comment: I'd recommend opening another issue on Github then.